# Xbee series 1 Data throughput decreases if data is increased

Tags: xbee, throughput

hi I have an xbee connected to my sensors which samples 14 bytes every 5ms. Other xbee is connected to PC.When is send 210K bytes of data at 115k baudrate my throughput will be 99% but when i increase the data to 700K at the same speed, throughput will be 69%. I am absolutely stumped. why is it that my throughput reduces drastically when i increase the number of data sent keeping the speed constant. Thanks

Comment: I would post this to the digi forum. You're more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Can you describe your setup in more detail?  Do you have hardware flow control enabled?  What does the 69% represent, lost data?  Does your network have more than just two nodes on it?  How are you sending your data (bursts of serial bytes in AT mode, or complete frames in API mode), and what are the packetization settings on the XBee?  Due to overhead, it's difficult to sustain 115kbps over an 802.15.4 network operating at 250kbps.